# SDK Manager is not running

Tags: android

Android SDK Manager is not running and I got the following messages in the console. Can any one please suggest me, how to come out of this problem?

```
[2013-08-08 20:39:31 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2013-08-08 20:39:31 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:346)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:320)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:120)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:103)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
[2013-08-08 20:39:32 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   ... 4 more
```

Comment: Well there are two relevant parts: `xcopy' is not recognized` and  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display`

Comment: can you please tell me, why does this happen? do you have any idea, what might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your classpath. Here's [a link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Installing+Oracle+JDK#InstallingOracleJDK-Windows)

Comment: set my classpath to what ?

Comment: @keerthi : May I know what classpath you had to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

logout and log back in after installing jdk. then the error disappears.
source- arch linux makepkg warning